menu de usuarios
tengo una duda, he creado este menu de creación de usuarios para una tarea que me han mandado en un grado que estoy haciendo, pero no consigo que se creen mas usuarios que 1, ya que si creo mas pisa el anterior creado y yo lo que quiero es que se vayan creando un usuario por línea.
Estoy empezando a usar Python ahora, de ah mi ignorancia, pido perdón por adelantado.
El codigo:
usuarios = open('Usuarios.csv', 'w')   
    usuario = (input('Nombre de usuario a crear: '))
    password = (input('Contraseña: '))
    ruta = (input('Ruta de documentos: '))
    usuarios.write(usuario)
    usuarios.write(';')
    usuarios.write(password)
    usuarios.write(';')
    usuarios.write(ruta)
    usuarios.write('\n')
    print('Usuario creado correctamente')


Hola buenas te comento tu problema ya que es muy común y tiene fácil solución
A la hora de abrir un archivo tenemos varias opciones

w = El archivo se abrira para escribir desde 0
r = el archivo se abrira para leer
a = el archivo se abrira para añadir en lugar de escribir desde 0

Y demas opciones te recomiendo que mires https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/lectura-y-escritura-de-archivos-en-python-como-crear-leer-y-escribir-archivos/ donde podras verlas todas
Por lo tanto si no quieres que solo se quede un usuario tu linea pasara de:
usuarios = open('Usuarios.csv', 'w')
a
usuarios = open('Usuarios.csv', 'a')

Usaría open(file, 'a+´) para crear el fichero si no existe
